# Updating QTableView with more rows dynamically

Tags: qt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I have a `QTableView`, which uses a model derived from `QAbstractTableModel`.

The model starts out with a number of rows and displays the data properly.

The model also has a timer attached to it, which upon expiring, gets the number of rows and columns, constructs an index for it, and emits dataChanged signal, to update the dynamic contents of the table.

The problem is when the number of rows it is supposed to display, changes.

In that case, even though I obtain a new index with the changed no. of rows, and update the table, it still doesn't display any new rows.

I've identified why, perhaps. Let's say I have 2 rows in the beginning, and next, 5 rows are supposed to be displayed. In the timer expiration logic, I've asked it to construct a new index, with new row count… but `dataChanged()` signal, will only change the data for the rows which had already been inserted in the first. The new rows are not displayed.

This is my code for the model.

```
TableLayout::TableLayout()
  : QAbstractTableModel()
{
  rowCount();
  columnCount();
  timer = new QTimer(this);
  timer->setInterval(3000);
  timer->start();
  connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerHit()));

  //ItemList[0].SetFields("Blah" ,"Blah" , "Blah" , "Blah" , "Blah", "Blah", true  );
  //ItemList[1].SetFields("Blah1" ,"Blah1" ,"Blah1" ,"Blah1" ,"Blah1", "Blah1", true );
}

void TableLayout::timerHit()
{
  int row = this->rowCount();
  qDebug() << "RowCOunt::" << row;
  qDebug() << " Now IT IS : " << row;
  int col = this->columnCount();
  qDebug() << "ColumnCOunt::" << col;
  QModelIndex Ind = createIndex( 0, 0);
  QModelIndex Ind1 = createIndex( row, col);
  data(Ind1);
  emit dataChanged(Ind, Ind1);
}

int TableLayout::rowCount(const QModelIndex& /*parent*/) const
{
  RtdbReader* rtdbReader = RtdbReader::instance();
  if (isConnected)
    return rtdbReader->Get_Number_of_Items();
  else return 2;
}

int TableLayout::columnCount(const QModelIndex& /*parent*/) const
{
  return 6;
}

QVariant TableLayout::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
  int row = index.row();
  int col = index.column();

  //return row;
  int row_count, col_count = 0;
  if ( role == Qt::DisplayRole) {

    if ( col == 1)
      return ItemList[row]->GetExplanation();
    if ( col == 2) {
      qDebug() << " Now printing Sig name for row" << index.row();
      return ItemList[row]->GetCond_Sig_Name();
    }
    if ( col == 3)
      return ItemList[row]->GetDescription();
    if ( col == 5)
      return ItemList[row]->GetLogic();
    if ( col == 4)
      return ItemList[row]->Get_State_Text();
  } else if ( role == Qt::DecorationRole && col == 0 ) {
    bool col_to_display = ItemList[row]->GetValueColour();
    qDebug() << "colour in view:" << col_to_display;
    if  ( col_to_display ) {
      QString path = "Green.png";
      //QPixmap p( s_type1Icon );
      // return s_type1Icon;

      QIcon icon ( path );
      return icon;
    } else {
      QString path = "Yellow.png";
      //QPixmap p( s_type1Icon );
      // return s_type1Icon;

      QIcon icon ( path );
      return icon;
    }
  }

  if (role == Qt::TextAlignmentRole )
    return Qt::AlignCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter;

  /* else if ( role == Qt::BackgroundRole)
   {
     QBrush yellowBackground(Qt::yellow);
              return yellowBackground;
   }*/

  return QVariant();
}
```

Please suggest how I can change the view so new rows are added.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just because you create a `QModelIndex` to the element at `row, col`, doesn't mean you created data for that element (and also not for the elements between the current end and that element).

You have to use `setData(...)` to add new data to the table, and then emit `dataChanged(...)` for the view to display it.

Comment: In this case, I'd wish to remove all the rows and insert new ones...something like a `reset`. If a reset is to be done, where should I do it? the data must always be o(btained, as you can see in the `data()` function, from the ItemList. So in the `timerHit()` slot, if I store the number of rows, and then if the new row count is different from the old, should I call `beginResetModel()`. Is this correct? Else, where should I have it?

Comment: I don't completely understand what you are trying to do.
If you really want to erase everything from the model, then I think you have to remove all the rows separately. Start with `beginRemoveRows(parent, 0, nrOfRows);`, then do `removeRows( 0, nrOfRows );` and then do `endRemoveRows( parent, 0, nrOfRows );`. And after that you can start inserting rows againg.
If you just want your view to do a complete update based on the data in the model, just use `QAbstractTableModel::modelReset()`.

Comment: I have a table with some rows. The number is not fixed. it could be anything in the beginning. Later..I might get a new number of rows. The content of those rows will be entirely different. Each row has 2 pieces of data that might need to change, so I used `dataChanged()` and got that to work in that way. But some input is there, which will contain new rows with different data of their own. In this case, am I better off with a reset, and if so, where can I put the reset? In the `timerHit()` in the code?

Comment: Ok, so don't use any reset function. Just remove all elements (all rows) and start adding rows again. You should do this where you have the input for the new rows.